# Android - Button spawning floating context menu

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, floating

Is it possible to have a button in Android open a floating context menu and if so, how? I'm not sure how to implement the floating context menu, let alone link it to a button so I mainly want to know if it's possible. But if it is, then how would be nice. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Dialog** instead on long press event. For example like when you longpress on android device home screen.

Comment: Hadn't considered this oddly, thank you - will look into it. Can I still use it on a button?

Comment: Yes you can call Dialog on Button press event.

Comment: And can I have each option in the menu open a new "page"? I'll select as best answer when the option becomes available. :-)

Comment: Yes, you can call different Activities on Dialog option click event.